# Can we open only english numpad for ionic capacitor for iOS?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, keyboard, capacitor, numpad

There is one scenario where I am stuck in an ionic capacitor.

We have one screen where users enter the amount.

I want them to enter the amount in only English so I want to open only English Numpad (0-9).

**I can put validation but there is specific requirement to open English numpad only.**

If I changed my keyboard language to other than English, and click on any number field, it shows Numpad in the previously selected language. I want English Numpad forcefully there.

Is it possible to achieve?

I am using **ionic capacitor**.

Thanks!

Comment: you can check the number on onChange method using this

var english = /^[0-9]*$/;
if (english.test(names[i])) // ...

Comment: @JainBhavesh Thanks.! As I mentioned in the question we don't want validation. We need Numpad forcefully.

Comment: That's not possible. cause ionic keyboard plugin can not provide such things.

Comment: But you can make your custom keyboard and show hide according to textbox's focus